# javascript Image editing using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am new to fabric.js plugIn and i need to select only floor with in an image and change its color when user select color options.How to do it?Is there any way other plugIn to achieve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean *select only floor with in an image* ?

Comment: Thanks for your response,Currently i am working on the project in which the user can upload their rooms,kitchens,halls,images and edit its floor with available tile images in app and check its view..so,i need to crop the floor area with in an image and replace with different tile images.

Comment: please add a minimal working snippet of what you did so far. you need to use patterns probably